# Parameters for AddAssemblyEvidence() of class Evidence C#

Tags: c#, .net

In .net framerwork 4.5, MS has deprecated `AddAssembly()`, and prompt developer to use `AddAssemblyEvidence()`.

Now, in my old code, I am passing `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName` as parameter to `AddAssembly()`.
But when I am passing the same parameter to `AddAssemblyEvidence()` I am getting compile time error that

> the type 'string' can't be use as type parameter 'T' in generic type. There is no implicit reference from string to `system.security.policy.evidencebase`

Comment: It was deprecated because programmers put too much nonsense in the evidence.  This looks like such a case, hard to see what the point might be of adding the assembly's full name.  It could only make a difference in a custom CLR hosting scenario.  Do try just commenting out the code first, document what exactly goes wrong when you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created to Projects one Console and the other one is DLL. 
in the DLL lib I have the following class:

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld2
{

  [Serializable]
  public class Class1
  {
    public Class1()
    {
    }

    public void ExcuteMe()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
  }
}
```

In the console app I'm calling the ExecuteMe method:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  using System;
  using System.Reflection;
  using System.Security;
  using System.Security.Policy;
  using System.Security.Principal;

  using HelloWorld2;

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var fullPathToDll = "HelloWorld2.dll";
      var domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup
      {
        ApplicationBase = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
        PrivateBinPath = fullPathToDll
      };

      var ev1 = new Evidence();

      ev1.AddAssemblyEvidence(new ApplicationDirectory(typeof(Class1).Assembly.FullName));

      ev1.AddHostEvidence(new Zone(SecurityZone.MyComputer));

      var ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Class1", ev1, domainSetup, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().PermissionSet, null);

      var identity = new GenericIdentity("Class1");
      var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);

      ad.SetThreadPrincipal(principal);

      var remoteWorker = (Class1)ad.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(
            fullPathToDll,
            typeof(Class1).FullName);
      remoteWorker.ExcuteMe();
    }
  }
}
```

You are free now the code above contains only the concept.

I think what exactly you need just this line:

**ev1.AddAssemblyEvidence(new ApplicationDirectory(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));**